# ASP.MVC NoCacheAttribute being ignored after ModelState.IsValid = true

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Using the following on my controller to always fire the HttpGet Action when user clicks browser back or `javascript:history.back()`:

```
<OutputCacheAttribute(VaryByParam:="*", Duration:=0, NoStore:=True)>
<HttpGet>
Function MyInformation() As ActionResult
...
End Function
```

It works perfectly in all but this scenario:

1. Submit view and `ModelState.IsValid = false` on the `<HttpPost>` Function due to validation issue(s)
2. Correct the errors and re-submit
3. `ModelState.IsValid = true`, so display next view
4. Hit Browser back or `javascript:history.back()`
5. Page is now showing a cached version with the validation messages and the Action is never executed

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do u mean u have set OutPutCache on a HttpPost action on submit ?

Comment: I only set the attribute on HttpGet, which I believe is correct.  I tried setting the attribute at the class level but no change.